# How to get reCAPTCHA data with Ajax

Tags: java, php, html, ajax, recaptcha

I would like to get "human" or "bot" with Ajax based on reCAPTCHA score, but it doesn't work... Could you give me any advice? You don't need to think about validation at this point.

html

```
<form id="contact-form" action="/" method="POST">
   <input type="hidden" name="recaptchaResponse" id="recaptchaResponse" />
   <input class="btn-send" type="button" name="send" value="SUBMIT">
</form>
```

script (ajax)

```
$(function() {

   $('.btn-send').on('click', function(e){
      e.preventDefault();

      //reCAPTCHA
      grecaptcha.ready(function() {
         grecaptcha.execute('my_key_here', {action: 'homepage'}).then(function(token) {
            var recaptchaResponse = document.getElementById('recaptchaResponse');
            recaptchaResponse.value = token;
         });
      });

      //ajax
      var formData = $('#contact-form');
      $.ajax({
         url: "/",  
         type: "POST",
         data: formData.serialize()
      })
      .then(

      function (data) {
         //I want to alert "human" or "bot" here
         alert(data);
      },
      function () {
         alert("fail");
      });
   }
});
```

php

```
if (isset($_POST['recaptchaResponse']) && !empty($_POST['recaptchaResponse'])) {
    $secret = 'my_key_here';
    $verifyResponse = file_get_contents('https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret='.$secret.'&response='.$_POST['recaptchaResponse']);
    $reCAPTCHA = json_decode($verifyResponse);
    if ($reCAPTCHA->score >= 0.7) {
         echo 'human';
         exit;
    } else {
         echo 'bot';
         exit;
    }
}
```

Comment: When u console.log($reCAPTCHA)  before the if - else loop - what do u get there?

Answer (score 0):

If ajax is giving you right data then just check at your ajax side if return value is `human` or `bot` depending on that display required alert .

Your function will look like :

```
function(data) {
  var values = $.trim(data); //triming value if there is any whitespaces
  if (values == "human") {
    alert("Hello you are human"); //show alert
  } else {
    alert("Hello you are Robot");
  }
}
```